# Troubleshooting WebSocket Connection Issue: Invalid Header Error When Accessing Python WebSocket Server

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, websocket

I'm currently developing a WebSocket server using Python. Here's the code snippet:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def server(ws:str, path:int):
    inp = input('Client joined. Greet it. \nType ')
    await ws.send(inp)
    while True:
        message = await ws.recv()
        print(f'Msg [{message}]')
        
Server = websockets.serve(server, "127.0.0.1", 8000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(Server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Accompanied by an HTML page (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And a JavaScript file (app.js):

```
function startSocket() {
  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000");
  ws.onopen = function (event) {
    ws.send("Sent this from client.js");
  };
}
startSocket();
```

Upon running the Python script and attempting to access 127.0.0.1:8000 on both Chrome and Safari, I encounter the following error message:

"Failed to open a WebSocket connection: invalid Connection header: keep-alive.

You cannot access a WebSocket server directly with a browser. You need a WebSocket client."

I'm seeking assistance in understanding why this connection issue is occurring and how to fix it.

The code I have written is very basic, and I took it directly from the documentation. I have also searched the web for a solution, but nothing satisfactory has been found. I am looking for any pointers that would help me understand the issue and fix it.